# How do i vertically center an image and 2 lines of text next to eachother?

Tags: html, css, css-position, vertical-alignment

Hello folks I ran into a problem today that I've been trying to fix for at least 2 hours now. Basically what I want is an image on the left and then 2 lines of text that are vertically aligned to the image (in a way where it is responsive).

A picture here of what i would like to get:

[image]

I've tried a bunch of things.
First I tried to put the image and the text in a separate div with `display: inline-block;` This made it so the text and image were next to each other but the text would be on the top.

I tried adding flexbox to this but this doesn't work since the `display: inline-block;` line would be overwritten.

I tried putting the image and text in the same div and using `vertical-align: middle;` This didn't work either because only the first line of text would be perfectly centered with the image and the second line would go below the image.

I've also been looking on stackoverflow for solutions for a while and on other sites I find with google aswell but I havn't found what I need.

The HTML of how my code is now:

```
<div class="projects">
    <img src="../Photos/kugelround6.jpg" alt="kugel logo" class="pic projects-pic">
    <span class="projects-text">Some text<br>Some more text</span>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.projects{

}

.pic{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.projects-pic{
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.projects-text{
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Also sorry if my english, grammar or code isn't the best, I'm only a jr dev.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you tu use `flexbox`:

```css
.projects{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="projects">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/150" alt="kugel logo" class="pic projects-pic">
    <span class="projects-text">Some text<br>Some more text</span>
</div>
```

You'll need media queries for responsiveness.

Comment: This indeed makes it so the 2 lines and image are next to eachother but now they arn't horizontally centered anymore?

Comment: Just add `justify-content: center;`. You can learn more about flexbox [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: Ah yes i forgot about that, thank you!